# `nicematrix` NiceTabularX alignment

Tags: nicematrix

I am trying to save horizontal space in a `nicematrix` `NiceTabularX` table as the report my table is going in has a page limit (the table is half a page long). I desire using `nicematrix` as I use `tikz`, `\tabularnote{}` and a coloured header which doesn't bleed in my main table so would prefer to use this. By way of an image, this is how my MWE table looked initially (colour added manually):

[image]

I have controlled the red distance so it is flush to the left margin by using `\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{@{}c!{}X}` (pg. 7 of the [`nicematrix` documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix)) but I do not know how to control the distance of the blue line. I want there to be some space but also want to control as I have pruned my table but reducing the space could perhaps save me a line or two which is desirable.

Using `{\textwidth}{@{}c!{}@{}l!{}}` produced this so I feel that I need the `X` column:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can control the distance between the first and second columns in a `NiceTabularX` table whilst allowing line breaks please? I cannot claim too much experience with tables so apologies if this is basic or asked before, I checked the `NiceTabularX` questions on here.

How it currently looks:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize

\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{@{}c!{}X}
\toprule
\textbf{Year} & \textbf{Important milestones or key achievements in de novo enzyme design}\\ \midrule
1983-84 & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\ \addlinespace[0.1em]
1994    & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\ \addlinespace[0.1em]
1995    & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\ \addlinespace[0.1em]
2000-04 & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\ \addlinespace[0.1em]
2010-14 & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\ \addlinespace[0.1em]
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabularX}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The horizontal amount of white space that is added to either side of the text in a cell is controlled via `\tabcolsep`. By default it amounts to 6pt. You can change this by using `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}` or any other value of your choice. Adding this to the preamble will affect all tables in your document, using it inside of the `table` environment will keep the effect locally.

Comment: Cannot believe it was that basic, so sorry!! Now I know, would you like to post as an answer please?

Comment: I would use `\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{@{} c X @{}}`  or rather `\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{@{} l X @{}}` and then see if the `\tabcolsep` is needed to be reduced too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't seem to be making effective use of the various easily available spacing options. For instance, you could insert `@{}` at both ends of the tabular-like environment in order to eliminate any unwanted whitespace padding at the *edges* of the tabular-like environment.

The amount of *intercolumn whitespace* is given by `2\tabcolsep`. To generate less of this whitespace, you can either set a smaller value for `\tabcolsep` (its default value is `6pt` in most document classes), or you can state directly how much whitespace you're willing to allow between columns 1 and 2 -- by writing, say, `@{\hspace{4pt}}` if `4pt` is the desired amount of whitespace.

I'm not sure if your real document makes further use of the machinery provided by the `nicematrix` package. As the following screenshot demonstrates, there's no  difference between using a `NiceTabularX` environment or just a plain old `tabularx` environment, for the code you've provided.

Oh, please do use `--` rather than `-` to generate typographic en-dashes between year groups.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx,nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs,lipsum}

\newcommand\blob{%
  \toprule
  \textbf{Year} & 
  \textbf{Important milestones or key achievements in de novo enzyme design}\\ 
  \midrule
  1983--84 & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\ \addlinespace[0.1em]
  1994     & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\ \addlinespace[0.1em]
  1995     & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\ \addlinespace[0.1em]
  2000--04 & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\ \addlinespace[0.1em]
  2010--14 & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\ \addlinespace[0.1em]
  \bottomrule}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize

\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{@{} l @{\hspace{4pt}} X @{}}
\blob
\end{NiceTabularX}

\bigskip

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l @{\hspace{4pt}} X @{}}
\blob
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Mico for the explanation, I need to get better with tables as they are my weak link. I have bookmarked your answer and will return to it in the future to get better, I accepted pretty quick as it explained and solved my issue and I am happy with it

Answer (score 3):

Well, you stres that solution should consider `nicematrix` package, but anyway use `tabularray` is a good alternative (which need to be compiled only ones):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \footnotesize
\begin{tblr}{colsep  = 4pt, % or desired amount
             colspec = {@{} l X[j] @{}},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries}
             }
    \toprule
Year    & Important milestones or key achievements in de novo enzyme design \\
    \midrule
1983-84 & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
1994    & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
1995    & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
2000-04 & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
2010-14 & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You may want to point out somewhere -- other than by referring the reader to the package's user guide... -- that setting `colsep  = 4pt` results in 2*4pt=8pt of intercolumn separation. Put differently, if the desired amount of intercolumn whitespace is `4pt`, one has to set `colsep = 2pt`.

Comment: +1 thank you for the answer, it could help future readers looking for an alternative, the more alternatives the better! `:)`

Comment: @Mico, of course.`colsep` define padding between column content and its left/right borders (as `\tabcolsep` do) For have distance between  contents of neighbour cells only 4 pt, then you should set `colsep=2pt`. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough earlier. I was just concerned that an untrained reader of your answer might confuse the setting `colsep = 4pt` with the total amount of intercolumn whitespace being `4pt` when, in fact, it's 2*4pt=8pt. (I'm quite aware of the fact that *you* are very much aware of this distinction.)

Comment: @Mico, you are right! Now I see, that you explain this in your answer. Do I add some words about this in my answer too?

Comment: @Mico, No luck with my answer :-(. Firs I upload it to wrong question -- so you beat me for four minutes ;-) -- now, when I try to upvote than your answer, crash my PC.  It seems that both are too old ... 